# Set and get value with factory, angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a service:

```
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    var test = 5;

    return{
      setTestVal: function(val){
        test = val;
      },
      getTestVal: function(){
        return test;      
      }
    }    
});
```

This is my controllers. One get the value and one sets it

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.test = myService.getTestVal();
}

function SetCtrl($scope, myService){
    $scope.newTestVal = '';
    $scope.setTestVal = function(val){
      myService.setTestVal(val)
    }
}
```

But the view is not updated when I set the value.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7036/

Is this the wrong approach to setting and getting values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this approach is perfectly fine, however the view has no idea when a new value is set, you have to setup a `$watch` on the shared property:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return myService.getTestVal();
}, function(value) {
    $scope.test = value;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7041/

Comment: Guess I'm getting to spoiled with the two way data binding. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You even could do it without $watch,
check fiddle i modified from yours :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    var test = 5;
    var obj = {
        test : 5
    }

    return{
      setTestVal: function(val){
        test = val;
        obj.test = val;
      },
      getTestVal: function(){
        return test;      
      },
      data : obj
    }


});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.test = myService.getTestVal();
    $scope.data = myService.data;
}

function SetCtrl($scope, myService){
    $scope.newTestVal = '';
    $scope.setTestVal = function(val){
      myService.setTestVal(val)
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/no9rv2nb/